# error source file android_asset www build vendor js ionic app content is not loading

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I run ionic cordova platform add android@6.4.0 and when i run my app with android studio:

I can log in well, but when the homespage comes, the data does not load, and in other pages as well. On every page i do a request, the data does not load, and at the exact same moment i tap on those pages, i see something like this(but with different number) in the console of android studio:

```
“ERROR”, source: file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js (any line)
```

More of what's inside android studio's logcat

```
08-12 10:44:10.611 8547-8547/io.ionic.starter I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1882)] "TOKEN EN GETORDER - CARRITOSERVICE.TS", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (1882)
08-12 10:44:10.611 8547-8547/io.ionic.starter D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 1883 : eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjdiYmU1YzA0ZDVmMTlkMWM0NDBkZTVkNGU0NWVjMDk2MjkzN2NjZDI1ODZiZmQxN2UxMjViOWUxYmM0YzZmZTA1MWE1N2RiNTM4NDRlMGIxIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyIiwianRpIjoiN2JiZTVjMDRkNWYxOWQxYzQ0MGRlNWQ0ZTQ1ZWMwOTYyOTM3Y2NkMjU4NmJmZDE3ZTEyNWI5ZTFiYzRjNmZlMDUxYTU3ZGI1Mzg0NGUwYjEiLCJpYXQiOjE1MzQwODEwOTEsIm5iZiI6MTUzNDA4MTA5MSwiZXhwIjoxNTM1Mzc3MDkxLCJzdWIiOiI1MDciLCJzY29wZXMiOltdfQ.egUykxz7sykM4DzOsdZLQax_-AZtoqlgyYVoPvYNgn8wz4DcH_2TZcVPY-tH-6D0FgqciPHsmPptaUqWQjEjtrcfTPKcN05qsz5DTavlDVOcLqW4CSvwld8QDf8FX_aVM4JAz7uarqkF11Zxl6pB_e0F6ayUdlslhlTMpmyBOXWB45_VH-MVlUFpkG2BLB1FzrzwrEKplcgOKKgArw8Fh_D8Y3Y-wnL8LmoVySJX0GBnULWQiGlSA808a8U2O1zP2onITRtSAPA90jd_JSKmjhrxxq4Gz0gePbQdlYp_wmQGzT9L1f_6VwenaDtvQ49d9V-MH2ZOYl3l1loU7UOr44PMRQ-_Ne1SZXujp4zvTJvJ_wBaCC1nCB_DwNnRNjqUodxjCojoZJgCRgPgoGhmoOZBLnoYxwrr-vGDl0BsJo9lhVLCzxO2ifJtMlp_2KrRdlqKQ4EJjgZq2l3bwIqjzx7sHVBkhLIJovAoxR3grwjtCL5vq1Ng3rEXt_j-LLMhuIxnLNM2CDJYfpv1_n8WFbL6m8J2JbzNZon_9wdsQbmebPTGh40MJkaJ7TCxp9jU2BuEiJORvlY6ud090jcZFmFJil3uqcTcOj5deUZjoyor8m72aTgMwzv2VRWf25CjSNHpaUlsqeLtnQzC_zyL8ilUA-KKEQDmzeOyh8_agOM
08-12 10:44:10.611 8547-8547/io.ionic.starter I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1883)] "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjdiYmU1YzA0ZDVmMTlkMWM0NDBkZTVkNGU0NWVjMDk2MjkzN2NjZDI1ODZiZmQxN2UxMjViOWUxYmM0YzZmZTA1MWE1N2RiNTM4NDRlMGIxIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyIiwianRpIjoiN2JiZTVjMDRkNWYxOWQxYzQ0MGRlNWQ0ZTQ1ZWMwOTYyOTM3Y2NkMjU4NmJmZDE3ZTEyNWI5ZTFiYzRjNmZlMDUxYTU3ZGI1Mzg0NGUwYjEiLCJpYXQiOjE1MzQwODEwOTEsIm5iZiI6MTUzNDA4MTA5MSwiZXhwIjoxNTM1Mzc3MDkxLCJzdWIiOiI1MDciLCJzY29wZXMiOltdfQ.egUykxz7sykM4DzOsdZLQax_-AZtoqlgyYVoPvYNgn8wz4DcH_2TZcVPY-tH-6D0FgqciPHsmPptaUqWQjEjtrcfTPKcN05qsz5DTavlDVOcLqW4CSvwld8QDf8FX_aVM4JAz7uarqkF11Zxl6pB_e0F6ayUdlslhlTMpmyBOXWB45_VH-MVlUFpkG2BLB1FzrzwrEKplcgOKKgArw8Fh_D8Y3Y-wnL8LmoVySJX0GBnULWQiGlSA808a8U2O1zP2onITRtSAPA90jd_JSKmjhrxxq4Gz0gePbQdlYp_wmQGzT9L1f_6VwenaDtvQ49d9V-MH2ZOYl3l1loU7UOr44PMRQ-_Ne1SZXujp4zvTJvJ_wBaCC1nCB_DwNnRNjqUodxjCojoZJgCRgPgoGhmoOZBLnoYxwrr-vGDl0BsJo9lhVLCzxO2ifJtMlp_2KrRdlqKQ4EJjgZq2l3bwIqjzx7sHVBkhLIJovAoxR3grwjtCL5vq1Ng3rEXt_j-LLMhuIxnLNM2CDJYfpv1_n8WFbL6m8J2JbzNZon_9wdsQbmebPTGh40MJkaJ7TCxp9jU2BuEiJORvlY6ud090jcZFmFJil3uqcTcOj5deUZjoyor8m72aTgMwzv2VRWf25CjSNHpaUlsqeLtnQzC_zyL8ilUA-KKEQDmzeOyh8_agOM", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (1883)
08-12 10:44:10.804 8547-8547/io.ionic.starter D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js: Line 1823 : ERROR
08-12 10:44:10.805 8547-8547/io.ionic.starter I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1823)] "ERROR", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js (1823)
08-12 10:44:42.247 8547-8547/io.ionic.starter D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 942 : ionViewWillEnter
08-12 10:44:42.247 8547-8547/io.ionic.starter I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(942)] "ionViewWillEnter", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (942)
08-12 10:44:42.249 8547-8547/io.ionic.starter D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 1858 : TOKEN EN GETCART - CARRITOSERVICE.TS
08-12 10:44:42.249 8547-8547/io.ionic.starter I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1858)] "TOKEN EN GETCART - CARRITOSERVICE.TS", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (1858)
08-12 10:44:42.250 8547-8547/io.ionic.starter D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 1859 : eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjdiYmU1YzA0ZDVmMTlkMWM0NDBkZTVkNGU0NWVjMDk2MjkzN2NjZDI1ODZiZmQxN2UxMjViOWUxYmM0YzZmZTA1MWE1N2RiNTM4NDRlMGIxIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyIiwianRpIjoiN2JiZTVjMDRkNWYxOWQxYzQ0MGRlNWQ0ZTQ1ZWMwOTYyOTM3Y2NkMjU4NmJmZDE3ZTEyNWI5ZTFiYzRjNmZlMDUxYTU3ZGI1Mzg0NGUwYjEiLCJpYXQiOjE1MzQwODEwOTEsIm5iZiI6MTUzNDA4MTA5MSwiZXhwIjoxNTM1Mzc3MDkxLCJzdWIiOiI1MDciLCJzY29wZXMiOltdfQ.egUykxz7sykM4DzOsdZLQax_-AZtoqlgyYVoPvYNgn8wz4DcH_2TZcVPY-tH-6D0FgqciPHsmPptaUqWQjEjtrcfTPKcN05qsz5DTavlDVOcLqW4CSvwld8QDf8FX_aVM4JAz7uarqkF11Zxl6pB_e0F6ayUdlslhlTMpmyBOXWB45_VH-MVlUFpkG2BLB1FzrzwrEKplcgOKKgArw8Fh_D8Y3Y-wnL8LmoVySJX0GBnULWQiGlSA808a8U2O1zP2onITRtSAPA90jd_JSKmjhrxxq4Gz0gePbQdlYp_wmQGzT9L1f_6VwenaDtvQ49d9V-MH2ZOYl3l1loU7UOr44PMRQ-_Ne1SZXujp4zvTJvJ_wBaCC1nCB_DwNnRNjqUodxjCojoZJgCRgPgoGhmoOZBLnoYxwrr-vGDl0BsJo9lhVLCzxO2ifJtMlp_2KrRdlqKQ4EJjgZq2l3bwIqjzx7sHVBkhLIJovAoxR3grwjtCL5vq1Ng3rEXt_j-LLMhuIxnLNM2CDJYfpv1_n8WFbL6m8J2JbzNZon_9wdsQbmebPTGh40MJkaJ7TCxp9jU2BuEiJORvlY6ud090jcZFmFJil3uqcTcOj5deUZjoyor8m72aTgMwzv2VRWf25CjSNHpaUlsqeLtnQzC_zyL8ilUA-KKEQDmzeOyh8_agOM
08-12 10:44:42.251 8547-8547/io.ionic.starter I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1859)] "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjdiYmU1YzA0ZDVmMTlkMWM0NDBkZTVkNGU0NWVjMDk2MjkzN2NjZDI1ODZiZmQxN2UxMjViOWUxYmM0YzZmZTA1MWE1N2RiNTM4NDRlMGIxIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyIiwianRpIjoiN2JiZTVjMDRkNWYxOWQxYzQ0MGRlNWQ0ZTQ1ZWMwOTYyOTM3Y2NkMjU4NmJmZDE3ZTEyNWI5ZTFiYzRjNmZlMDUxYTU3ZGI1Mzg0NGUwYjEiLCJpYXQiOjE1MzQwODEwOTEsIm5iZiI6MTUzNDA4MTA5MSwiZXhwIjoxNTM1Mzc3MDkxLCJzdWIiOiI1MDciLCJzY29wZXMiOltdfQ.egUykxz7sykM4DzOsdZLQax_-AZtoqlgyYVoPvYNgn8wz4DcH_2TZcVPY-tH-6D0FgqciPHsmPptaUqWQjEjtrcfTPKcN05qsz5DTavlDVOcLqW4CSvwld8QDf8FX_aVM4JAz7uarqkF11Zxl6pB_e0F6ayUdlslhlTMpmyBOXWB45_VH-MVlUFpkG2BLB1FzrzwrEKplcgOKKgArw8Fh_D8Y3Y-wnL8LmoVySJX0GBnULWQiGlSA808a8U2O1zP2onITRtSAPA90jd_JSKmjhrxxq4Gz0gePbQdlYp_wmQGzT9L1f_6VwenaDtvQ49d9V-MH2ZOYl3l1loU7UOr44PMRQ-_Ne1SZXujp4zvTJvJ_wBaCC1nCB_DwNnRNjqUodxjCojoZJgCRgPgoGhmoOZBLnoYxwrr-vGDl0BsJo9lhVLCzxO2ifJtMlp_2KrRdlqKQ4EJjgZq2l3bwIqjzx7sHVBkhLIJovAoxR3grwjtCL5vq1Ng3rEXt_j-LLMhuIxnLNM2CDJYfpv1_n8WFbL6m8J2JbzNZon_9wdsQbmebPTGh40MJkaJ7TCxp9jU2BuEiJORvlY6ud090jcZFmFJil3uqcTcOj5deUZjoyor8m72aTgMwzv2VRWf25CjSNHpaUlsqeLtnQzC_zyL8ilUA-KKEQDmzeOyh8_agOM", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (1859)
08-12 10:44:42.263 8547-8547/io.ionic.starter D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js: Line 1484 : ionViewDidLeave PedidosPage
08-12 10:44:42.263 8547-8547/io.ionic.starter I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1484)] "ionViewDidLeave PedidosPage", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (1484)
08-12 10:44:42.432 8547-8547/io.ionic.starter D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js: Line 1823 : ERROR
08-12 10:44:42.432 8547-8547/io.ionic.starter I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1823)] "ERROR", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js (1823)
08-12 10:44:42.590 8547-8547/io.ionic.starter D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js: Line 1823 : ERROR
08-12 10:44:42.590 8547-8547/io.ionic.starter I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1823)] "ERROR", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js (1823)
08-12 10:44:43.905 8547-8547/io.ionic.starter D/CordovaActivity: Paused the activity.
08-12 10:44:43.971 8547-8547/io.ionic.starter D/CordovaActivity: Stopped the activity.
```

**This is the ionic info:**

```
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v8.9.4
    npm               : 5.6.0
    OS                : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\JulioD07\Desktop\sdk

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Comment: Problem solved. Noob mistakes, running android for version 6.4.0 and issues appending headers solved the problem.

Comment: hi did you fix the issue, i am also facing same issue

Comment: Well from what i remember, i had two problems, one was with the headers, try to run it with ionic cordova run android --prod -lcs and check the console.

Comment: I also have this problem. Would have been really helpful to have more information about your fix

Comment: It's something very general, i mean, my problem was that my headers to an api that i got, they were wrong. So when i enter on any page, the data did not load, and it was because the request were wrong due to the mistakes that i did setting up the headers. But i was able to log in, because the login was in another way.

Try to use some console logs to see where the vendor problem should be, and also, try to test/debug the app using `ionic cordova run android --prod -lcs` before that you need to run `ionic cordova platform add android@6.4.0` and in that way you will be able to see what happens